# NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsarray, selector

I receive a memory leak for the line containing the sortedArrayUsingSelector definition. Does anybody know what might be the problem?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *indexLetters;
...
NSMutableDictionary *indexedCategories = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
...
self.indexLetters = [[indexedCategories allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
[indexedCategories release];
```

Comment: What is being done in `compare` method?

Comment: It's a default comparing selector. I don't implement any compare method. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: What is telling you, you're leaking? Instruments or the static analyzer?

Answer (score -1):

It could be because you're not releasing the `indexLetters` variable in `dealloc`.

Comment: That is not clear from your code sample. You're releasing the `indexedCategories` variable, but memory management regarding the `indexLetters` instance variable is not shown.

Comment: Not really sure why this got voted down. If the `indexLetters` instance variable is not released correctly, it WILL cause a leak. It doesn't seem to be the reason in this case (from Dorin's comment) but it's still a valid point.