# Can an autoreleased NSArray cause a memory leak?

Tags: ios, nsarray, retain, autorelease

I am trying to create an NSMutableArray using arrayWithArray, add two objects, sort, and store to an ivar as an NSArray. My code looks like this:

```
NSMutableArray *_mutableItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.mainViewController.someDictionary allKeys]];

[_mutableItems addObject:@"Buildings"];
[_mutableItems addObject:@"Parking"];

self.curItems = [_mutableItems sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

When I profile the app I get a memory leak for an NSArray after the view is popped. But what I don't understand is: aren't all of these objects autoreleased? Am I increasing the retain count when I assign it to the instance property?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829741/nsarray-sortedarrayusingselector-memory-leak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, setting the property is probably increasing the retain count. Specifically, `_mutableItems` will be autoreleased, but the array you create with `sortedArrayUsingSelector`is retained by the property.

Does your property declaration include `retain` or `copy`?

```
@property (retain) NSArray *curItems;
```

If so, in your class `dealloc` method, make sure you call `release` on the array;

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [curItems release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```